# Binary Tree Inorder Traversal Order

Tags: binary-tree, nodes, traversal

I have this binary tree that I have to list the order of its inorder traversal:

```
            B
           /  \
          G    C
         / \    \
        M   H    D
         \   \    \
          N   I    E
                  / \
                 J   F
                / \   \
               O   K   G
```

I know that it goes like so: left -> root -> right

*My answer as of now is:*

M, N, G, H, I, B, C, D, O, J, K, E, F, G

*With explanation:*

M(leftmost), N, G, H, I, B(root), C(right), D, O, J, K, E, F, G

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is correct. Not exactly a programming question, though.

Comment: Ooops my apologies :( Where should I have posted this?